# will CTE run again if we join in other CTE or with a main query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, sqlperformance, postgresql-performance

I have a question regarding whether CTE in a query runs only once or every time it is getting joined.

Causing we are facing a CPU consumption issue in postgres metrics.

if it runs only once then fine. if not we need to optimize the query. is there any way in postgres SQL to make a CTE run only once?

below is the example query. removed complex logic in each of cte's for brevity and avoid confusion in question. the main CTE (i.e, current_student_temp  in this case) is crucial one it needs to be  used for further processing.

```
with current_student_temp as (
select * from 
 (select sd.student_id ,sd.school_id,
  sd.first_name ,sd.last_name ,
 ROW_NUMBER() 
 OVER (PARTITION by sd.student_id 
       ORDER BY sd.school_id ) AS rowNum
 from basics.student_appt_details sd
 )school_appts_for_student
where rowNum=1
),

race_cd_temp as (
select rc.student_id ,rc.race_cd  as race
 from basics.race_details rc 
 inner join current_student_temp cst on cst.student_id = rc.student_id 
 --will current_student_temp run again here? breakpoint-1
),

citizenship_temp as (
select ct.student_id ,ct.citizenship  as citizenship
 from basics.citizenship_details ct 
 inner join current_student_temp cst on cst.student_id = ct.student_id 
 --will current_student_temp run again here? breakpoint-2
), 

gender_temp as (
select gt.student_id ,gt.gender  as gender
 from basics.gender_details gt 
 inner join current_student_temp cst on cst.student_id = gt.student_id 
 --will current_student_temp run again here? breakpoint-3
)


select * from basics.person
left join current_student_temp cst on cst.student_id = person.student_id 
left join race_cd_temp rct on rct.student_id = person.student_id 
left join citizenship_temp ct on ct.student_id = person.student_id 
left join gender_temp gt on gt.student_id = person.student_id
```

Any input is highly appreciated.

Comment: no it will create a temporary table and then use like such

Comment: I suggest refactoring the query replacing the CTEs for race, citezenship, and gender with `LEFT JOINS` to the base tables in the main query.

Comment: This has been flagged as a duplicate; however, the answer in the older question doesn't take into account changes that were made as of PostgreSQL 13. Without explicitly marking the CTE with `MATERIALIZED`, there are conditions under which the CTE might be executed more than once.

Comment: @JohnH thanks for comment. so using MATERIALIZED for CTE's will work and make it execute only once ?. and this is dummy query in actual query we have lots of logic in  CTEs for race, citezenship, and gender  . i just removed for brevity.